# Sorting Dates in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I have dates in an excel spreadsheet I need to sort.  They are formatted as month and day, ex: 9/12.  I want to be able to sort so that all months and days are in sequence starting 1/1 to 12/31.  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: What happens now?  Why won't the current sort options work?

Answer (score 0):

If the data is being stored as "string" data... (meaning it starts with an apostrophe) You'll need to remove the `'`.  If Excel doesn't display the date in the format you want, you'll simply need to select a different format... not convert it to a string.

Once the data is in the proper date format, it will sort as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you pasted the data from other sources, you will need to make Excel recognise them as dates. Even if the cells are formated as date, you will need to "edit" all cells (you double click the cell and after click enter or select another cell), so that Excel internally converts the information displayed to dates.